# Gradle Kotlin, Cucumber, and OKHttp

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, cucumber

I'm trying to set up a spring boot project in Kotlin with OkHttp and Cucumber and getting the following error when running the cucumber task.  How do I fix?

```
Execution failed for task ':cucumber'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':cucumberRuntime'.
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.3.1
      > Cannot choose between the following variants of com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.1:
          - jvm-api
          - jvm-runtime
          - metadata-api
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'jvm-api' capability com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.1:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Found org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but wasn't required.
                  - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
                  - Found org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'jvm' but wasn't required.
          - Variant 'jvm-runtime' capability com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.1:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Found org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but wasn't required.
                  - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
                  - Found org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'jvm' but wasn't required.
          - Variant 'metadata-api' capability com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.1:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
                  - Found org.gradle.usage 'kotlin-api' but wasn't required.
                  - Found org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'common' but wasn't required.
```

and the build gradle kts snippet

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.5.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.61"
}

group = "com.foo"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

val developmentOnly by configurations.creating
configurations {
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom(developmentOnly)
    }
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")

    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.3.1")
    implementation("com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter:6.0.1")
    runtimeOnly("com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:6.0.1")
    runtimeOnly("com.graphql-java-kickstart:voyager-spring-boot-starter:6.0.1")

    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-java8:5.4.0")
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:5.4.0")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

val cucumberRuntime by configurations.creating {
    extendsFrom(configurations["testImplementation"])
}

task("cucumber") {
    dependsOn("assemble")
    dependsOn("compileTestJava")
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
            classpath = cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.get().output + sourceSets.test.get().output
            args = listOf("--plugin", "pretty", "--glue", "gradle.cucumber", "src/test/resources")
        }
    }
}
```

I saw this error https://github.com/square/okio/issues/647 that seems like it could be it and a fix with this build.gradle, how would I translate this to kotlin for a build.gradle.kts?

```
subprojects { subProject ->
  ...

  configurations.all { configuration ->
    // Workaround for kapt bug with MPP dependencies
    // https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-31641
    // https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33206
    if (name.contains('kapt') || name.contains("wire")) {
      attributes.attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, subProject.objects.named(Usage.class, Usage.JAVA_RUNTIME))
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution yet? I came across the same problem and can't seem to find a fix either...:(

Comment: The only mentioned solution was to add that subprojects hack shown above, but I couldn't translate that from a groovy based gradle file to kotlin kts gradle file- maybe you can try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this line is the key:

```
 > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':cucumberRuntime'.
```

In https://github.com/square/okio/issues/647, this is:

```
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':main:kapt'.
```

So they used "kapt" as the name. In MonkeyBonkey's case, he will need to use:

```
configurations.all {
    if (name.contains("cucumberRuntime")) {
        attributes.attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Usage::class.java, Usage.JAVA_RUNTIME))
    }
}
```

This worked for me with yet another name in my case: "productionRuntimeClasspath"

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem like you 
I would translate the proposed workaround like this:

```
configurations.forEach {
        if (it.name.contains("kapt") || it.name.contains("wire") {
            attributes.attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Usage::class.java, "java-runtime"))
        }

    }
```

But this fix did not solve the problem for me because I don't have any configurations for either `kapt` nor `wire`.